# Redirecting out of Partial View leaves embedded page

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I've got a partial view in C# with a from that has some AJAX refresh stuff going on. However, when I submit the form, the function called ends with `return RedirectToAction("newaction");`, and instead of redirecting the entire page to that, replaces the partial view on the page with the new page, so that I have the header and footer twice. Why might this be happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: it will ofcourse render it this way as it is ajax call you need to redirect via javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is posted via ajax, it will return the action view in ajax response, so you have to return `JavascriptResult` instead of `RedirectToAction` like this:

```
return JavaScript("window.location='"+Url.Action("SomeAction","SomeController")+"'");
```

or if you want to refresh page then:

```
return JavaScript("location.reload(true)");
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to redirect in javascript after your call is completed.

For Example:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "/directory/find/",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {  },
            success: function (data) {
                //The redirect upon success
                window.location = data.URL;
            }
        });
```